# LinkedList functions crash in c

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I implemented a linked list in c. when i test it, whenever i reach display function or insert at the end the program crashes. These are the functions:

```
    struct Node
    {
        char data;
        struct Node *next;
    };
    struct LinkedList
    {
        struct Node *head;
    };
       void insertAtBeginning(struct LinkedList *LL, char ele)
{
    struct Node *new = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new->data = ele;
    new->next = NULL;
    if(new->data == '\n')return;
    if(LL->head==NULL)LL->head = new;
    else
    {
        new->next=LL->head;
        LL->head=new;
    }
}
void insertAtTheEnd(struct LinkedList *LL, char ele)
{
    struct Node *new = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new->data = ele;
    new->next = NULL;
    if(LL->head==NULL){LL->head=new;return;}
    struct Node *current = LL->head;
    while(current->next != NULL) {current = current->next;}
    current->next = new;
}
void deleteNode(struct LinkedList* LL, char ele)
{
    struct Node *current = LL->head;
    struct Node *temp = LL->head;
    while(current->next->data!=ele && current!=NULL)current=current->next;
    temp=current->next; 
    current->next=current->next->next;
    free(temp);
}
void deleteFirstNode(struct LinkedList* LL)
{
    struct Node *temp;  
    if(LL->head != NULL)
    {
        temp = LL->head;
        LL->head = LL->head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
void displayLinkedList(struct LinkedList LL)
{
    struct Node *current = LL.head;
    printf("List: ");
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%c",current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
        printf("\n");
}
```

This is the main:

```
    main()
{
    struct LinkedList LL;
    char c = '0';
    //Inserting at beginning
    printf("Type a string. Press Enter to end: ");
    while(c != '\n')
    {
        scanf("%c",&c);
        insertAtBeginning(&LL, c);  
    }
    printf("List: ");
    displayLinkedList(LL);
    printf("\n");
    //Inserting at end
    c='0';
    printf("Type a string. Press Enter to end: ");
    while(c != '\n')
    {
        scanf("%c",&c);
        insertAtTheEnd(&LL, c);     
    }
    printf("List: ");
    displayLinkedList(LL);
    printf("\n");
    //Remove
    printf("Enter a char to remove: ");
    scanf("%c",&c);
    deleteNode(&LL, c);
    printf("\n");
    printf("List: ");
    displayLinkedList(LL);
    printf("\n");
    deleteFirstNode(&LL);
    printf("List: ");
    displayLinkedList(LL);
}
```

of course This is done after inserting the necessary libraries.

Comment: Your `main` method has no return type?

Comment: set the "next" of your new node to NULL, immediately after you create it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to set `NULL` to next when you create element. if you do not do it, your while loop behaviour will be buggy

```
void insertAtTheEnd(struct LinkedList *LL, char ele)
{
    struct Node *new =  (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new->next = NULL;
    new->data = ele;
    if(LL->head == NULL) LL->head = new;
    else
    {
    struct Node *current = LL->head;
    while(current->next != NULL) {current = current->next;}
    current->next = new;
    }
}
```

, and do same for other functions.

also you have to set `NULL` to your `LinkedList.head`. so, set `NULL` when you define `LinkedList`

```
struct LinkedList LL;
LL.head = NULL;
```

Comment: Ok. but it is still crashing too. same as display function

Comment: display functions seems ok. I suggest check other functions. one of function might still have non initializing "next" property

Comment: it always crashes when using the first display after `insertAtBeginning` loop. The problem is in one of these two functions.

Comment: the problem might come because of you are using non-pointer LinkedList in your display method. can you convert it to take pointer, and send your LinkedList's address, just like other functions. for the first two line of display function should be, void displayLinkedList(struct LinkedList* LL)
{
    struct Node *current = LL->head; ...

Comment: @hzjw, I found the problem. when you create LinkedList itself, you dont assign its header. so, if (LL->head== NULL) never works. you should init head of LinkedList just after you define it. so, 
 struct LinkedList LL;
 LL.head = NULL;  would be enough. and also I suggest use pointer in display function too

Comment: You are the best. Thank you very much. if it doesn't bother you please write the solution as an answer so i can accept it. Thank you again.

Comment: you can accept this. I put this note also to the answer

Answer (score 0):

i asume the line   if(current = LL->head) is wrong
bacause temp = current->next would crash if the result is NULL
otherwise the code after the if statement doesnt makes sense

Comment: if `current->next` is `NULL` it will not enter the loop at all

Comment: either the condition is allways true then the code after the if block will never be reached or it will crash because current is NULL

Answer (score 0):

There are some instances where you will try to insert at the end.  When you have something of the form `node_new->next->prev = node`, you must check to make sure that `node_new->next` is not NULL, because NULL does not have any type and thus does not have a `prev` field.

You may also consider making all of your functions return `int`, so that you can know if and what goes wrong.